# Laravel localization does not work: locale isn't changed

Tags: php, laravel, session, localization

I'm trying to make localization with Laravel, but my code doesn't work, some opinion or advices?

Here is the code:

**My `Language` middleware `handle()` method:**

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Session::has('locale')) {
        $locale = Session::get('locale', Config::set('app.locale'));
    } else {
        $locale = "bg";
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```

**My controller method:**

```php
public function changeLang(Request $request,$lang) {
    if (!empty($request)) {
        Session::put('locale',$lang);
    } else {
        Session::set('locale',$lang);
    }
    return back();
}
```

And here is my route:

```php
Route::get('/{lang}','LanguageController@changeLang');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: When i get route /en , it not change language or do anything!

Comment: you all routes looking like this /{lang}/some/action?

Comment: check SessionMiddaleware in your Kernel class

Comment: I check it i registered my middleware in global http middleware stack `protected $middleware`i mean

Comment: This might be helpful https://codezen.io/implementing-auto-localization-in-laravel-based-on-users-location/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this code will work for you.

**Controller**

```
   public function index($locale) 
  {
      session(['locale' => $locale]);
      App::setLocale($locale);
      return Redirect::back();
   }
```

**Language Middleware:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }
        else { // This is optional as Laravel will automatically set the fallback language if there is none specified
            App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/{lang}', 'LanguageController@index');
```

Last add your Langauge middleware in app/Http/Kernal.php in middlewaregroup

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
```

Comment: what is the difference with the question? an explanation will be better to have.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding my middleware in middleware groups!

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```